# How to get my code to output a specific piece of text from an existing spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am currently working on a combination restriction on my VBA code where individuals can not select certain options together. At the moment the code works, yet on the log page where I am displaying all errors I can not get the code to show the two combinations that are restricted (referring to the code '& rs.Cells(r, 4) &'). I really want the log to state the two modules that are restricted and I'm stuck/confused as to the text I need to enter to ensure this happens.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
excluded = True
    For r = 3 To rs.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rq.Rows(i), rs.Cells(r, 4).Text) > 0 And _
            WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rq.Rows(i), rs.Cells(r, 5).Text) > 0 Then
            excluded = False
        End If
    Next r
    
    If excluded = False Then
        logNextRow = logNextRow + 1
        lg.Cells(logNextRow, 1) = studentID
        lg.Cells(logNextRow, 2) = "Student selected restricted combination - " & rs.Cells(r, 4) & ""
        isLog = True
        'GoTo nxti
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the logging to inside the loop.

```vb
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String
    For r = 3 To rs.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
        s1 = rs.Cells(r, 4).Text
        s2 = rs.Cells(r, 5).Text
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rq.Rows(i), s1) > 0 And _
            WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rq.Rows(i), s2) > 0 Then
            logNextRow = logNextRow + 1
            lg.Cells(logNextRow, 1) = studentID
            lg.Cells(logNextRow, 2) = "Student selected restricted combination - " & s1 & " " & s2
        End If
    Next r
```